# Need pop up alert solution

Tags: apex, javascript

When a user selects a specific option in a picklist, we need an pop up to alert them of their choices ramifications and to allow them to continue to save or not to save the document.

How to approach this?

Comment: Where you want this scenario? Either On VF Page or Standard Page?

Comment: It for a Standard Page

Comment: You can use the Custom Button (Executing Javascript). You can give the specific condition and alert accordingly...

Comment: Ok but how does it work. If javascript returns false then saving is stopped and if true it saves the document? Do you have a sample of how to get this done?

Comment: Ohh Sorry, If you don't want to save the record and just show the error means, You have to use validation rule. But if you need the Alert Statements means, you should write a vf page and need to show the alerts from that vf page's javascript

Comment: Are you bored? This was 1.5 years ago.